# Covariance between two random variables with different number of values?

Tags: probability, random-variable, covariance

Let's say I have a RV $X$ with values $100$, $200$ and their associated probabilities, and some RV $Y$ with values $35$, $47$ and $862$ with associated probabilities.

What does it even mean to find the covariance of those Random Variables? Looking at the formula it looks like we're doing $$(x_1 - \mu_x) (y_1 - \mu_y) P(x_1 \cap y_1) + (x_2 - \mu_x) (y_2 - \mu_y) P(x_2 \cap y_2) + ... + (x_n - \mu_x) (y_n - \mu_y) P(x_n \cap y_n)$$.

How does that make sense if the random variables have different numbers of values?

Comment: Where did you get that formula?  Of course you need to know the joint probability of all combinations of values from X and Y in order to compute their covariance. So basically, you will have a double summation, and the number of terms (variable values) in each sum need not be the same.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, sorry for the late reply and thanks for the clarification. The formula was in the prof's slides. That's why I was confused because there was only a single summation symbol and a single index, so it didn't really make any sense if we assume different data set sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more typical way to write out the covariance of two discrete random variables would be:
\begin{align}
Cov(X, Y) = E[(X - \mu_X)(Y - \mu_Y)] = \sum_x \sum_y (x - \mu_X)(y - \mu_Y)P(X=x, Y=y)
\end{align}
In your case you would get:
\begin{align}
(100 - \mu_x)(35 - \mu_y)P(X=100, Y=35) +
(100 - \mu_x)(47 - \mu_y)P(X=100, Y=47) +
\dots
+ (200 - \mu_x)(862 - \mu_y)P(X=200, Y=862)
\end{align}
So in short I think that what you are missing is that you should be summing over all possible pairs of outcomes, giving you $3\times 2 = 6$ things to sum over.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. In our slides there was only a single summation symbol and a single index, so I couldn't make sense of it in the context of data sets of different sizes. It makes sense now.